# How to Display °C Symbol in Excel from database?

Tags: vba, excel, visual-studio-macros

I am using a excel File which has a cell contain  °C Symbol with other string (Ex.. -40°C
)

And i am trying to get the value of that cell using

```
    Dim strIn As String
    strIn = Range("B2").Text
```

All working fine and strIn has a value "-40°C"  but once i changed My Regional setting as follows..

[image: Regional setting]

it started to shows strIn  values as "-40?c"

[image: Debug Mode]

0° symbol is changed with ??

Thanks in advance for any help..
Liyo Jose.

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation in the VBA IDE. It can only show a total of 255 different characters (some of which are not printable). This will be the first 128 characters of standard Ansii, and then the rest will be determined by the codes in your regional settings.

VBA shows ? because it cannot display ° (because ° is not within the character code list for your settings). When you go through the rest of your code, it should perform exactly as you would expect and correctly readd ° to your sheet.

If you want to use ° within VBA, you will need to utilize it's character code. From my testing, you can generate it via `Chrw(176)` at least on my computer (Yes, I did change my regional settings to Thai for you). To check the codes you can run through them with a loop. Now as I said before, the IDE will display ?, but Excel will show °.

You can confirm this by running this test on your code:

```
debug.print Instr(strIn, "?")
'Should be 0
debug.print Instr(strIn, chrw(176))
'Should be 4
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel For such a detailed explanation and try.. Actually i have a Records set in in i have string which contain -40°C,-60°C etc and i use   dataSheet.Range(dataSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1), dataSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1)).CopyFromRecordset allData </br> For writing recorset to excel sheet, But even in excel sheet it rendering as 
-40?C

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution is to replace the "?" symbol in the string. A statement like

```
strIn = Replace(strIn, "?", "°")
```

Should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

assuming your symbol will never be something that can affect the value, `val` should give you the data you are after.

example data:

```
text   val()
40°C    40
40?C    40
40%C    40
40C     40
```